# Cannont take in multiple inputs

Tags: python, google-apps-script

i have this code in the google apps script.

```
function createDocument(invoice_id,cust_name)
 {
  var TEMPLATE_ID = 'practice_link';  
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy().getId();
  
  drivedoc = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  drivedoc.setName("Invoice " + invoice_id);
  
  doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText('{invoice_id}', invoice_id);
  body.replaceText('{cust_name}',cust_name);
  
  drivedoc.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);

  return "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + documentId + "/export?format=pdf";
}


function doGet(e) {
  var invoice_id = e.parameter.invoice_id;
  var cust_name = e.parameter.cust_name;
  var url = createDocument(invoice_id,cust_name);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(url);
}
```

when i use the link :

url?invoice_id=1,    it runs properly

but when i try :

url?invoice_id=1&cust_name=customer

it runs but does not make changes for cust_name.

and if i try:

url?cust_name=customer

it shows the error

Exception: Invalid argument: replacement (line 12, file "Code")

after many tries i realised that it is showing this error only for when i use, cust_name=str .

please help me out here.i have many more parameters to pass and m stuck here.
i ll be using this app with python to pass on the parameters

Comment: Where is the error occurs in your script? And, when you redeployed the Web Apps as new version and test it again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: please confirm speling **{cut_name}** or **{cust_name}** in code line body.replaceText('{cut_name}',cust_name);

Comment: @Deven, it is {cust_name}

Comment: @Tanaike, line 12 shows error ,which should be the 13th.
which is, 
Line 13:
body.replaceText('{cust_name}',cust_name);

Comment: @InderjeetSinghYadav please update the same in question

Comment: Yep did it already.
one more thing i would like to add.
i had already deployed this script before and at that time there was no statement for the cust_name.
basically there was only one parameter i.e. invoice_id.
and afterward when invoice_id was working i made the changes in the script for the cust name.
does it update the script i have the deployed link for.
i m new to this google apps script.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the scenarios you've mentioned, error only occurs when the `invoice_id` parameter is missing and adding cust_name won't affect the code. Those are hints that the URL you are trying to access is outdated or the script changes you've made is not yet deployed.

> url?invoice_id=1, it runs properly
>
> but when i try :
>
> url?invoice_id=1&cust_name=customer
>
> it runs but does not make changes for cust_name.

Also, `Exception: Invalid argument: replacement (line 12, file "Code")` indicates that the 2nd parameter of `body.replaceText(pattern, value)` in line 12 is undefined. This part should error too for cust_num if the deployed application is updated and the parameter for cust_num is missing.

Follow these steps on how to deploy script as web app:

> At the top right of the script project, click **Deploy > New deployment**.
>
> Next to "Select type," click Enable deployment types **settings > Web app**.
>
> Enter the information about your web app in the fields under "Deployment configuration."
>
> Click **Deploy**.

You can also use the test environments to evaluate your application and to make sure that the output of your project is correct before deploying. See [Test a deployment.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#test_a_deployment)